# How can I run a TraceRt as if I were at another IP address?

Tags: cloudflare

I'm trying test whether my hosting company is blocking traffic from certain IP addresses*.

I'd like to confirm that by running a TraceRt between the Cloudflare server IP and our server's IP address.

***Background**
I"m using CloudFlare and they are returning a Cached version of our site to some users.  They indicated that this can be caused by a Host blocking some of their server IP addresses.

Comment: This should not be possible. If it is possible, then it needs to be stopped, or it will be used to DDoS people.

Answer (score 0):

For Cloudflare Enterprise customers it is possible to use the [following API](https://api.cloudflare.com/#diagnostics-traceroute). It allows to run traceroutes from Cloudflare's edge data centers for diagnostic purposes.